# MyApp_language-xx.appx is not generated for Windows 10 package for store

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, appx, appxmanifest

I'm creating a package of my **UWP** App for Microsoft store.

My app supports 3 languages: English - default, Swedish and Danish.

If I do not manually clean up **obj and bin** folder then the generated MyApp.appxbundle file do not contain language packs: **MyApp_language-sv.appx, MyApp_language-da.appx**, as a result my app can not be localized to those languages.

I do not want to cleanup the folders each time. Any ideas except creating a script to delete the folders on build?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to cleanup the folders each time. Any ideas except creating a script to delete the folders on build?

For doing this, you could add the following into `YourProject.csproj` file.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <!-- Remove obj folder -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
    <!-- Remove bin folder -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseOutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

**Steps**

*Unload Project*

[image]

*Edit .csproj file add the above to the file.*

[image]

*At last reload your project.*